# Mysql queries giving error after upgrading

Tags: mysql, sql, database

why this simple query not working. I know it was OK before I upgraded my mysql version. i know there are some syntax changes in new version that I done. but this is simple query no join, but not working.

```
SELECT * FROM ship WHERE sensitive='Y' and entry_date between  $startdate and $enddate
```

Please help me.

**EDIT:**

Upgraded from mysql4 to mysql5 and error is 'syntax error'

Comment: You should state what is the error, and what is old and new mysql version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you upgraded from mysql 4 to 5 . sensitive is new [reserved keyword](https://web.archive.org/web/20161203120615/http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in mysql5. You need to enclose it in backticks(`) while using it in query.
Mysql 5 allows reserved words to be used is query but with backticks.

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM ship WHERE  `sensitive`='Y' and entry_date between  $startdate and $enddate
```

Answer (score 0):

You have "space" character in the '$start date'. That might be one reason. So, if your $startdate and $enddate are timestamps:

```
SELECT * FROM ship WHERE `sensitive`='Y' and entry_date between $startdate and $enddate
```

if they are not timestamps, but date in iso format, but them in single quotes.

Comment: That was typo mistake .but in actual query there is n space. anyway thanks for pointing that out